# Fibre bundles over interval are trivial - but in a smooth way?

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles

I'm trying to understand the homotopy invariance theorem for smooth fibre bundles.
A main step is to show that the interval $[0,1]$ only admits trivial fibre bundles.

I found [this proof](https://www.math.ru.nl/~mgroth/teaching/algtopII14/Section11.pdf) (see Lemma 3) in the topological setting. In the very last step the author "glues" the previously constructed maps $ \varphi_i $ together to receive a global trivialisation, which is evidently well defined and a homeomorphism. But in the smooth world, I cannot find reason for smoothness here.
I know proofs of the theorem for vector bundles by choosing a connection and parallel sections, but I need the statement for general fibre bundles. Anywhere I can find this proof?